# SUM does not calculate the sum of all amounts

Tags: sum, abap

I'm trying to sum up some values but it keeps giving me weird values. I'm posting the code to help, and an image too of what is happening.

```
at end of kunnr.    

 soma-waers = <fs_main-waers.
 soma-wrbtr = <fs_main-wrbtr.
 soma-fwste = <fs_main-fwste.
 soma-hwaer = <fs_main-hwaer.
 soma-dmbtr = <fs_main-dmbtr.
 soma-hwste = <fs_main-hwste.
 APPEND soma TO it_soma.  



LOOP AT it_soma INTO soma.
   IF sy-tabix = 1.


     FORMAT COLOR COL_TOTAL INTENSIFIED OFF.
     SUM.
     WRITE: "/ sy-uline(137),
           / sy-vline NO-GAP,
             'Subtotal' NO-GAP,
            '-' NO-GAP,
            soma-waers,
            63 sy-vline NO-GAP,
            64 soma-wrbtr NO-GAP,
            sy-vline NO-GAP,
            soma-fwste NO-GAP,
            sy-vline NO-GAP,
            soma-hwaer NO-GAP,
            sy-vline NO-GAP,
            soma-dmbtr NO-GAP,
            sy-vline NO-GAP,
            soma-hwste NO-GAP,
            sy-vline NO-GAP,
           / sy-uline(137).


   ELSE.
   ENDIF.

 ENDLOOP.

 ENDAT.
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I needed to clear the internal table in the end. It's working properly now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think you made a wrong code sequence.

Inside a `LOOP` you can use `AT-ENDAT`. Do not use a `LOOP` inside the `AT-ENDAT` like in your code.

Your code should more look like this:

```
LOOP AT it_soma INTO soma.
  AT END OF kunnr.    
     FORMAT COLOR COL_TOTAL INTENSIFIED OFF.
     SUM.
     WRITE: "/ sy-uline(137),
           / sy-vline NO-GAP,
             'Subtotal' NO-GAP,
            '-' NO-GAP,
            soma-waers,
            63 sy-vline NO-GAP,
            64 soma-wrbtr NO-GAP,
            sy-vline NO-GAP,
            soma-fwste NO-GAP,
            sy-vline NO-GAP,
            soma-hwaer NO-GAP,
            sy-vline NO-GAP,
            soma-dmbtr NO-GAP,
            sy-vline NO-GAP,
            soma-hwste NO-GAP,
            sy-vline NO-GAP,
           / sy-uline(137).
  ENDAT.
ENDLOOP.
```

Other sources of Problems:

- Your table must be sorted